# Retrieve childs of dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have the following code, which will output the child-elements of the "weather" element.

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weather")[0].childNodes;

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {  
        var parent = x[i].nodeName;
        document.write("<b>"+parent+"</b><br />");

    }
```

This will get the following childs:

> forecast_information, current_conditions, forecast_conditions,
>   forecast_conditions, forecast_conditions and forecast_conditions.

Now I want to retrieve all the childs of those elements. Probably with a loop inside a loop, that's why I tried the following:

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {  
    var parent = x[i].nodeName;
    document.write("<b>"+parent+"</b><br />");

    y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(parent)[i].childNodes;

    for (h=0;h<y.length;h++) {
        var child = y[i].nodeName;
        document.write(child+"<br />");
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.. It wil get the output:

> forecast_information
>
> city (7 times)
>
> current_conditions

Thats all.. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do another call to getElementsByTagName. Just use childNodes on each element in your loop to get the children's children:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weather")[0].childNodes;
var xlen = x.length;

var i, j, y, ylen;
for (i = 0; i < xlen; i++) {  
    document.write("<b>" + x[i].nodeName + "</b><br />");

    y = x[i].childNodes;
    ylen = y.length;

    for(j = 0; j < ylen; j++) {
        document.write(y[j].nodeName + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: @dimitri010 You're welcome :) Don't forget to declare all your variables too, so that they don't become globals.